# Understanding the structure of python code

Tags: python, syntax

Does anyone know of any useful resources to learn the structure of python code? When I say structure, I'm referring to the ingredients necessary to make the code correct, so a combination of syntax and the order of terms etc.

For example, to understand the type of a pandas dataframe, df, (I know, I've already identified that it's a dataframe, but just hypothetically), we type: type(df). For the shape, we write df.shape.

So, in the latter, why do we put df first, as in type(df)? Yet in the former, we put df last, and in parenthesis as in type(df). So, mixing these commands up, one may write df.type and expect to get an answer, but they wouldn't. So how do we learn these rules? I have searched high and low for some guidance, but I find very little; a lot of the guides assume you have an appreciation of these rules and don't explain them.

I'm not asking for help on this particular problem. Rather, I'm looking for a resource that would enable me to understand this, and the multitude of other rules better.

Comment: Really, it just sounds like you need to work through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) if you are having trouble distinguishing between functions and attributes.

Comment: Fyi, you can not ask opinion based questions on this site. Check out [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In what way is my question asking for an opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a Computer Science background, so my answer might be unorthodox or incomplete. There are things which come across as inconsistent when you use Python, and these things often trick me when I write new code. So you can easily find yourself looking up the same stuff time and time again.

However, I would say that the more you practice, the less likely it is to make mistakes or be confused. One good tip is to create a OneNote page with all the snippets that usually trip you up. Maybe by going back to that same snippet you will end up saving yourself time and fix those concepts in memory. It will cost you nothing, so give it a try.